# Why do I receive this error? [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm working on a program that converts certain letters from a string given by the user, like a=4, e=3 and so on. I want to declare that I'm still a beginner and I've been looking around for an answer but I can't find anything that helps me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void reemplazarLetras(string cadena);

void iterar(string cadena);

int main(){

    string cadena;

    do{
       cout << "Escribe una cadena de texto de entre 5 y 50 caracteres" << endl;
       getline(cin, cadena);
    }while(cadena.length() < 5 || cadena.length() > 50);

iterar(cadena);

cout << "Tu nueva cadena transformada es: " << cadena << endl;

}

void reemplazarLetras(string cadena){
    //Primero se reemplazan las vocales
    cadena.replace(cadena.find("a"), 1, "4");
    cadena.replace(cadena.find("e"), 1, "3");
    cadena.replace(cadena.find("i"), 1, "1");
    cadena.replace(cadena.find("o"), 1, "0");
    //Despues se reemplazan las consonantes s y t
    cadena.replace(cadena.find("s"), 1, "5");
    cadena.replace(cadena.find("t"), 1, "7");
 }

 void iterar(string cadena){
    for_each(cadena.begin(), cadena.end(), reemplazarLetras);   
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear why `iterar` needs a loop, since the parameter is a single string, and `reemplazarLetras` requires a single string.

Comment: [Sure about that error message?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/072a7c200a172b7e)

Comment: BTW, you are **passing a copy of the string** to `remplazarLetras`.  Any changes made will be to the *copy*.  If you want to make changes to the original string, pass by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my way to do it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void reemplazarLetras(char c);
void iterar(string cadena);

string cadena;

int main(){

     do{
         cout << "Escribe una cadena de texto de entre 5 y 50 caracteres" <<endl;
         getline(cin, cadena);
     } while (cadena.length() < 5 || cadena.length() > 50);

     iterar(cadena);

     cout << "Tu nueva cadena transformada es: " << cadena << endl;
     fflush(stdin);
     cin.get();
}
void reemplazarLetras(char c){
     //Primero se reemplazan las vocales
     int x;

     x = cadena.find("a");
     if (x != -1)
         cadena.replace(x, 1, "4");

     x = cadena.find("e");
     if (x != -1)
         cadena.replace(cadena.find("e"), 1, "3");

     x = cadena.find("i");
     if (x != -1)
         cadena.replace(cadena.find("i"), 1, "1");

     x = cadena.find("o");
     if (x != -1)
         cadena.replace(cadena.find("o"), 1, "0");

     x = cadena.find("s");
     if (x != -1)
         cadena.replace(cadena.find("s"), 1, "5");

     x = cadena.find("t");
     if (x != -1)
         cadena.replace(cadena.find("t"), 1, "7");
}

void iterar(string cadena){
     for_each(cadena.begin(), cadena.end(), reemplazarLetras);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `iterar` argument `cadena` is a string. When you iterate over that string, you iterate over its characters. Thus, C++ tries to apply `reemplazarLetras` to each character of `cadena` (and such characters have type `char`). Unfortunately, your `reemplazarLetras` function doesn't accept arguments of type `char`: instead it takes one argument `string cadena`. That causes C++ compiler to complain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better approach for your problem

And by the way, you should avoid using global variables in your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void replaceVowelsWithNumbers(string &cadena,const unordered_map<char,char> &map){
    transform(cadena.begin(),cadena.end(),cadena.begin(),
    [&map](char&c)-> char{return map.find(c)!=map.end() ? map.find(c)->second : c;});
}

int main(){
    unordered_map<char,char>letters;
    letters['a']='1';
    letters['e']='2';
    letters['i']='3';
    letters['o']='4';
    letters['u']='5';
    string cadena;
    getline(cin,cadena);
    replaceVowelsWithNumbers(cadena,letters);
    cout<<cadena<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```